# I want to find the sum of squares of digits in a number, my code work fine for positive numbers but doesn't seem to work with negative numbers

Tags: python

```
N=int(input('enter a number'))
sum=0
for digit in str(N):
            sum=sum+(int(digit))**2
print(sum)
```

This code works totally fine with positive numbers but How do I make it work for negative numbers too?

Comment: Just a heads up, you probably shouldn't use the word "sum" as a variable name because it is also the name of a Python function. I would recommend using total instead. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why do you think should it work for negative number? You are iterating through each character in `N` using `for digit in str(N)` if its `-23` then according to your code, the first iteration will have `digit=-`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) 
Writing code is only half of programming. Learning how to debug your programs is crucial to becoming a better programmer. Step through your code with an input that breaks it. Observe what each line does and confirm that it does what you expected it to do. What errors do you get, if any? "here's my code, debug it for me" is too broad for Stack Overflow. You must ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: Well with negative digits aren't you going to have input like `-123` and then you are trying to cast the string `"-"` as a digit in `sum=sum+(int(digit))**2`. Don't you want to make sure its a digit before you do that? Like maybe add an `if` statement to check?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) to find digits:

```
import re
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
sum = 0
for digit in re.findall(r'\d', str(num)):
    sum = sum + (int(digit))**2
print(sum)
```

You can also use a more compact and more Pythonic [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sum_sq = sum([int(i)**2 for i in re.findall(r'\d', str(num))])
```

Finally, the initial conversion of the input to `int` and subsequent casting of it back to `str` is not needed. Putting it all together:

```
import re
num = input('Enter a number: ')
sum_sq = sum([int(i)**2 for i in re.findall(r'\d', num)])
print(sum_sq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input to positive with `abs()`.

```
N=abs(int(input('enter a number')))
total=0
for digit in str(N):
    total=total+(int(digit))**2
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank a ton Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

You could skip characters that are not digits.

```
N = input('enter a number')
total = 0
for digit in [int(d) for d in N if d.isdigit()]:
    total = total + digit**2
print(total)
```

(note: I also removed the unnecessary conversion of the input at the beginning, but maybe you want an error to be raised if it is not a whole number. In this case, just put it back and replace `N` in the list comprehension by `str(N)`)

Comment: Thank you PacO :)